# Cant see contact "last seen online time"

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Does this contact not want me to see when last he was on line then? I can send him messages as well as chat.

Answer (score 2):

It may mean that your contact is using a privacy option to keep that information private:

https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/20971848

"Through our privacy settings, you have the option to control who can see your last seen."

There are a few reasons why you may not be able to see a contact's last seen:

- They may have set their privacy settings to hide this information.
- You may have set your privacy settings to not share your last seen.
- If you do not share your last seen, you cannot see other people's last seen.
- You may have been blocked.